# Error en sentencia sql

Tags: sql

Llevo mucho tiempo usando esta sentencia, pero nunca habia necesitado ponerle un where, por lo que ahora me está dando errores:
Nota:Necesito hacer el where con lo que va en el campo 'cedula_us'
Lo que quiero hacer es condicionar con un id que obtengo de una variable de sesión.
Me imprime este error:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected string content "", expecting "-" or identifier or variable or number in C:\xampp\htdocs\proyectofinalv2\lista.php on line 8

```
require_once("conexion.php"); 
session_start();
$cedula_us=$_SESSION['cliente'];
$columns=['cedula_us','estadoMiniTractor','estadoMonocultor','estadoMezcladora','estadoAtomizar','estadoMotosierra','estadoRotador','fecInicial', 'fecFinal', 'provincia', 'precioTotal'];
$table = "reservacion";

$sql =("SELECT  ". implode(",", $columns) . " FROM $table where cedula_us= '$cedula_us'");
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);
$num_rows = $resultado->num_rows;
```

Resuelto.

Comment: Pues el WHERE va después del `FROM table`. Lo otro es que no sabemos qué error será el que tienes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrias checar y leer mas [aqui](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp) sobre como usar los where, este va después de tu `FROM $table`, dado que no das que condición quieres para tu cedula_us, te pondré como ejemplo buscando cierta cedula_us, quedándote de la siguiente forma

```
$sql ="SELECT  ". implode(",", $columns) . "
FROM $table where cedula_us = 5";
```

Acerca del error que te despliega, podrías proporcionarnos que te arroja para ayudarte

Comment: Gracias por responder, te explico a la vez que edito la pregunta. Lo que quiero hacer es condicionar con un id que obtengo de una variable de sesión, intenté hacerlo similar a como lo muestras en ese ejemplo, pero me daba error.

Comment: Podrías mostrar el error que te arroja?  puedes hacer uso de ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);  al inicio de tu codigo en php

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected string content "", expecting "-" or identifier or variable or number in C:\xampp\htdocs\proyectofinalv2\lista.php on line 8

Me imprime esto, lo agregaré a la pregunta

Comment: estuve haciendo pruebas y lo logré, gracias por tu ayuda, pondré la respuesta por si alguien la necesita